# How to copy data from a view of one server into the database table of another server in a SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server, groovy, database-table

how can i copy data from a view of one server into the database table of another server in a SQL server database without using linked servers method.
I tried using the code:

```
SELECT [LogEntryID]
      ,[TimeStamp]
      Into [server-2].[database1].[dbo].[table1]
  FROM [server-1].[database1].[dbo].[view_1]
```

I recieve the error " The object name 'server-2.database1.dbo.table1' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
The copying statement i am using in a groovy code. But for first i am trying it in a query if it works.

Comment: what about insert into table1 from view_1 does that give you the same error?

Comment: I used INSERT Into [server-2].[database1].[dbo].[table1]  SELECT * FROM [server-1].[database1].[dbo].[view_1] . I got an error Could not find server 'server-1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
It can be done using linked servers but i don't want to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **opendatasource** instead of linked server

```
insert DestinationTable
select * from opendatasource('SQLOLEDB', 'Server=SourceServer;User Id=Username;Password=Password;').SourceDb.Schema.SourceTable;
```

[OPENDATASOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)